# How to know which is the first-child of an element?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with different entries. Sometimes the first item of this entry is a `<ul>` and sometimes it's a `<p>`. How can I test which one it is?

Here is an example with the first item `<p>`:

```
<div class="itsanyclass">
  <h3>XYC</h3>
  <div id="job123">
    <p>blablabla</p>
    <ul>
      <li>blablabla</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here's an example with the first item a `<ul>`:

```
<div class="itsanyclass">
  <h3>XYC</h3>
  <div id="job123">
    <ul>
      <li>blablabla</li>
    </ul>    
    <p>blablablabla</p>
  </div>
```

I tried this:

```
if($(":first-child", this) == "ul")
```

The class `.this` means its the object which called the function.

Comment: `$(this).children().first().prop('tagName') === 'ul'` or `$(this).children('ul:first-child').length > 0`, and probably a couple of others. You are trying to compare a **jQuery object** to a **string**, which will never work. I guess the question is: Why do you want to do this? Maybe there is a better solution to the overall problem than testing the type of the first child.

Comment: my thoughts were, testing if the first child is ul, if not it is definitly p

Comment: And my question was *why* do you need to know the type? What are you doing with this information? What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems with your code:

```
if( $(":first-child", this) == "ul" )
```

Firstly, it looks like you expect `this` in JavaScript to refer to the `<div>` with `class="this"`, but that's not what `this` means in JavaScript. In JavaScript `this` is a variable that [refers to the current scope](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html). If you want to get the element with `class="this"`, you need to use the `.this` selector:

```
console.log( $(".this") );
// => [<div class="this"></div>]
```

Now, to get the first child of the `div` inside `.this`, you need to do this:

```
console.log( $(".this > div > :first-child") );
// => [<p>blablabla</p>]
```

You might think you can get away with just `".this :first-child"`, but you can't—without the immediate child selectors (`>`), `:first-child` will return every element that's the first child of *any* of `.this`'s children.

Now that we've selected the correct element (which will be a `<p>` or a `<ul>`), we use jQuery's `is()` function to test whether or not it matches a given selector, i.e. `.is('ul')` will return `true` only if the selected element is a `<ul>`.

In the end, what we have is this:

```
if( $('.this > div > :first-child').is('ul') ) {
  console.log('First child of .this is a UL');
}
```

Comment: You need to dig a level deeper for the UL/P

Comment: @user3558931 OP has `<div class="this">`, which is why I used `.this` as a selector. I agree that `this` is not a very good class name, but the code is correct for the markup given.

Comment: @Jordan i am sorry, i mean with class this that this $(this) dont know how to say it right.

Comment: @Salix I'm not sure I've interpreted what you want correctly, but I've updated my answer to clarify the difference between `this` and `$(".this")` in jQuery.

Comment: @Jordan i edited my code so its more specific. Now when i say "this" i mean the div where the magic happens
console.log( $(".this") ); 
// => [<div class="itsanyclass"></div>]

what you gave me is exactly what i need, but i dont know how it works with this
if( $(this+'> div > :first-child').is('ul') )

Comment: @Salix My code should still give you a good idea how to solve your problem with any markup. First select the correct element using `:first-child` (making sure you're only selecting immediate children), then use `is()` to test if it matches the `ul` or `p` selector. That's all there is to it!

Comment: @Salix: Look at DOM traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 0):

You could use contains. I did this for a project I was working on where the content was also in first or second child elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('element').on('click', 'element:contains("blablabla")', function(){
        alert('you clicked me');
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could just add a class or id to the element and call that

Comment: I don't really see how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: Why is that? It demonstrates how the op could find the element regardless of how many children are between it and the parent

Comment: What makes you think the OP wants to find the `li` element?

Comment: In the question that is the same text that is in the p element. I presume the text will be different in the p and the li. I would think that both the li and p tags would have different text. If the text is different the op could target that text they are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I respect the answers from others but, I suppose the exact question is... "Which is the first type element?"

Although other answers maybe correct, still to exactly answer the question you may try this:

```
var first_child = $('.this > div > :first-child');
alert($(first_child).prop('tagName'));
```

And ofcourse, for associating functional code to your detected type you can use `.is()` as already shown in one the answers.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/zLwL2/